# Theme seems to have different options on wordpress.com and own-server install

Tags: themes, wordpress.com-hosting

I am trying to transfer a blog from wordpress.com to my own server. The site on wordpress.com uses the Origin theme, with a custom header image set. I have installed that theme on Wordpress on my own server, but I don't seem to have the option to select a header image.

If I look at the options under Appearance, on my own site they are:

- Themes
- Widgets
- Menus
- Background
- Theme Settings
- Editor

(and there is nothing under Theme Settings about a header image)

but on wordpress.com the options are:

- Themes
- Widgets
- Menus
- Header
- Background
- Custom Design
- Mobile

Is there any way for me to get the Header options (including the Header Image setting) for my own personal install? Alternatively, is there a simple way to edit the theme code to fix a header image in there? I would look at the theme code on wordpress.com, but of course there isn't an option to edit it there.

Comment: Add a link to the theme’s source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many times, the same theme for self-hosted will be different that the same for .com because of the way .com works and the choices theme authors and .com make for their offered themes.

If you want, you can download the theme from https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/ and match the code or adapt that theme to work on self-hosted. But it may take some work modifying the functions file, etc.

The Origin theme is at https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/origin/ . Use an `svn` client to download the theme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients or download each file and compare to the self-hosted version.